# Is there a formula for the $k$th smallest number of $n$ real numbers?

Tags: real-numbers, order-statistics

Let $a_{(k)}$ be the $k$th smallest number of $n$ real numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$. Is there a formula for $a_{(k)}$?

I know $a_{(1)}$ can be found recursively using
$$a_{(1)}=\min\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\},\\
\min\{a,b\}=\frac{1}{2}\left[ a+b-\lvert a-b\rvert\right],\\
\min\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1}\}=\min\{\min\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\},a_{n+1}\}.$$
Similarly, $a_{(n)}=\max\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ can be found with $\max\{a,b\}=\frac{1}{2}\left[ a+b+\lvert a-b\rvert\right]$.

Comment: For $a_{(2)}$, can you look at the min of all subsets of size $n-1$, and then take the max of that?

Comment: @user51547 Looks good to me. Do you have a source for the generalization of this method?

Comment: I couldn't find a source, but hopefully the generalization and its proof should be straightforward